# How to post a dynamic keyvalue pair arry in form asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, dynamic-data

I am trying to do some dynamic form post to server

something is organized like below:

```
Quiz
==>Question 1: value
==>Answer 1: value
...
==>Question N: value
==>Answer N: value
```

The form is created dynamically on client end first, then get post to server. 
As a result he server dose not know how many Question/Answer pairs they are expecting.

What would be the best practice in this case?

Comment: How are the Q&A pairs wrapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is two links that end up helping me to come up a solution:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

hopefully they will be helpful to you guys too.

Comment: You did not post what your particular solution was

Answer (score 0):

register a hiddenfield in the page, and after creating the question/answers on clientside, set the hiddenfield value via javascript, then do a postback and read the hiddenfield value in codebehind. also, a question/answer pair is a usual key/value pair, in codebehind use a dictionary instead of an array for that.